# How to develop an application lock for android

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to develop an application lock for android. I have also coded the classes that used the Services but then it gets an error. Saying this:

Logcat result:

```
 09-12 06:42:38.745: D/AbsListView(23708): Get MotionRecognitionManager
09-12 06:42:39.775: W/ResourceType(23708): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
09-12 06:42:39.775: W/PackageManager(23708): Failure retrieving resources forcom.sec.android.providers.tasks: Resource ID #0x7f020000
09-12 06:42:39.955: W/ResourceType(23708): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
09-12 06:42:39.955: W/PackageManager(23708): Failure retrieving resources forcom.android.providers.telephony: Resource ID #0x7f020000
09-12 06:42:40.455: W/ResourceType(23708): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
09-12 06:42:40.455: W/PackageManager(23708): Failure retrieving resources forcom.sec.android.provider.logsprovider: Resource ID #0x7f020000
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/ResourceType(23708): Failure getting entry for 0x7f060000 (t=5 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708): Failure retrieving text 0x7f060000 in package com.android.keyguard
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f060000
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1382)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1198)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:135)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at com.the.voiceapplock.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/ResourceType(23708): Failure getting entry for 0x7f060000 (t=5 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708): Failure retrieving text 0x7f060000 in package com.android.keyguard
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f060000
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1382)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1198)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:135)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at com.the.voiceapplock.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
09-12 06:42:41.165: W/PackageManager(23708):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-12 06:42:41.455: I/dalvikvm-heap(23708): Grow heap (frag case) to 31.920MB for 5676496-byte allocation
09-12 06:42:41.905: W/ResourceType(23708): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
09-12 06:42:41.905: W/PackageManager(23708): Failure retrieving resources forcom.sec.android.provider.badge: Resource ID #0x7f020000
09-12 06:42:42.035: D/dalvikvm(23708): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6242K, 31% free 22150K/31740K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
09-12 06:42:42.045: I/dalvikvm-heap(23708): Grow heap (frag case) to 30.897MB for 4194320-byte allocation
09-12 06:42:42.455: W/ResourceType(23708): Failure getting entry for 0x7f02001e (t=1 e=30) in package 0 (error -75)
09-12 06:42:42.455: W/PackageManager(23708): Failure retrieving resources forcom.samsung.shareshot: Resource ID #0x7f02001e
09-12 06:42:42.665: D/dalvikvm(23708): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1116K, 25% free 27178K/35840K, paused 19ms, total 20ms
09-12 06:42:42.745: W/ResourceType(23708): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
09-12 06:42:42.745: W/PackageManager(23708): Failure retrieving resources forcom.sec.android.providers.security: Resource ID #0x7f020000
09-12 06:42:43.425: D/dalvikvm(23708): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1749K, 19% free 30131K/36960K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
09-12 06:42:44.025: D/dalvikvm(23708): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1800K, 18% free 32527K/39316K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
09-12 06:42:44.245: W/ResourceType(23708): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
09-12 06:42:44.245: W/PackageManager(23708): Failure retrieving resources forcom.sec.android.Kies: Resource ID #0x7f020000
09-12 06:42:44.525: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:44.535: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:44.555: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:44.565: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:44.575: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:44.585: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:44.595: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:44.605: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:44.615: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:44.635: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:44.645: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:44.655: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:44.665: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:44.795: I/Adreno-EGL(23708): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
09-12 06:42:44.795: I/Adreno-EGL(23708): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
09-12 06:42:44.795: I/Adreno-EGL(23708): Build Date: 03/21/14 Fri
09-12 06:42:44.795: I/Adreno-EGL(23708): Local Branch: AU200+patches_03212014
09-12 06:42:44.795: I/Adreno-EGL(23708): Remote Branch: 
09-12 06:42:44.795: I/Adreno-EGL(23708): Local Patches: 
09-12 06:42:44.795: I/Adreno-EGL(23708): Reconstruct Branch: 
09-12 06:42:44.905: D/OpenGLRenderer(23708): Enabling debug mode 0
09-12 06:42:45.055: I/Choreographer(23708): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-12 06:42:45.285: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:45.285: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:45.285: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:45.285: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:45.285: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:45.285: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:45.295: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:45.295: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:45.295: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:45.295: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:45.295: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:45.295: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:45.295: D/TextLayoutCache(23708): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
09-12 06:42:45.385: D/AndroidRuntime(23708): Shutting down VM
09-12 06:42:45.385: W/dalvikvm(23708): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417e2da0)
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708): Process: com.the.voiceapplock, PID: 23708
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.the.voiceapplock.StartUpReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.the.voiceapplock.StartUpReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.the.voiceapplock-188.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.the.voiceapplock-188, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2619)
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:172)
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1384)
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.the.voiceapplock.StartUpReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.the.voiceapplock-188.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.the.voiceapplock-188, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2614)
09-12 06:42:45.395: E/AndroidRuntime(23708):    ... 10 more
09-12 06:42:53.425: I/Process(23708): Sending signal. PID: 23708 SIG: 9
```

I found that the error is the class StartUpReceiver cannot be found. But I have ensure that the classname that I declare in the android manifest is the same as the reference class. And now, I don't know how to fix the error. Please kindly help.
Here's the codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private ListView list;
    ArrayList<Model> data;
    ApkAdapter adapter;
    private PackageManager packageManager;
    TextView tView;
    ProtectAppProvider pap;
    CheckBox chk;
    ArrayList<String> protectedApps;
    List<PackageInfo> appsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();
        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appname);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.applist);
        appsList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
        data = new ArrayList<Model>();
        for (int i = 0; i < appsList.size(); i++) {
            PackageInfo p = appsList.get(i);
            if (packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(p.packageName) != null
                    || (!(p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager())
                            .toString().equals("VoiceAppLock")))) {
                Model model = new Model();
                model.setAppName(p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(
                        getPackageManager()).toString());
                model.setAppIcon(p.applicationInfo
                        .loadIcon((getPackageManager())));
                data.add(model);

                Collections.sort(data, Model.AppComparator);

            }
        }
        adapter = new ApkAdapter(MainActivity.this, data, packageManager,
                protectedApps);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_bar, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        boolean isChecked;
        boolean diditwork = true;
        int getPosition = (Integer) view.getTag();
        Model obj = data.get(getPosition);
        String apps = obj.getAppName();
        protectedApps = new ArrayList<String>();
        pap = new ProtectAppProvider(getApplicationContext());
        if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
            try {
                isChecked = true;
                data.get(getPosition).setSelected(isChecked);
                protectedApps.add(apps);
                pap.open();
                pap.createEntry(apps);
                pap.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                diditwork = false;
            } finally {
                if (diditwork)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        } else {
            isChecked = false;
            data.get(getPosition).setSelected(isChecked);
            diditwork = true;
            try {
                pap.open();
                protectedApps.remove(apps);
                pap.deleteEntry(apps);
                pap.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                diditwork = false;
            } finally {
                if (diditwork)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Fail to delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
            }
        }

    }

    private void initialize() {

        // Start receiver with the name StartupReceiver_Manual_Start
        // Check AndroidManifest.xml file
        getBaseContext().getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(
                new Intent("StartUpReceiver_Manual_Start"));
    }
}
```

StartUpReceiver.java

```
 public class StartUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static final String TAG = "SR";

    final int startupID = 1111111;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Create AlarmManager from System Services
        final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        try{
                // Create pending intent for CheckRunningApplicationReceiver.class 
                // it will call after each 5 seconds

                Intent i7 = new Intent(context, LockApps.class);
                PendingIntent ServiceManagementIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                        startupID, i7, 0);   
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 
                        5000, ServiceManagementIntent);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Exception : "+e);
            }

        }

}
```

LockApps.java

```
public class LockApps extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public final String TAG = "CRAR";
    private ArrayList<String> protectedApps;
    private ProtectAppProvider pap;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context aContext, Intent anIntent) {
        protectedApps = new ArrayList<String>();
        pap = new ProtectAppProvider(aContext);
        String appname = "";
        pap.open();
        Cursor c = pap.getData();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                appname = c.getString(0);
                protectedApps.add(appname);
            } while (c.moveToNext());

        }
        pap.close();

        try {

            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) aContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<RunningTaskInfo> li = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            Iterator<RunningTaskInfo> i = li.iterator();
            PackageManager pm = aContext.getPackageManager();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                try {
                    ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo info = (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo) (i
                            .next());
                    String ac = info.baseActivity.getPackageName();
                    CharSequence cs = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(ac,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
                    String app = cs.toString();
                    if(protectedApps.contains(app)){
                        Toast.makeText(aContext, "Hahahaa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Throwable caught: " + t.getMessage(), t);
        }
    }
}
```

Android Manifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.the.voiceapplock"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/applauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".StartUpReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="StartUpReceiver_Manual_Start" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name = ".LockApps"/>

    </application>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define two new methods in the main activity or the singleton class that you use to set global app variables.You may need to use shared preferences to get the time values to compare.

```
public void pause(Activity act) {
        // Record timeout time in case timeout service is killed    
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();     
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(act);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
        edit.putLong("Timeout_key", time);// start recording the current time as soon as app is asleep
        edit.apply();
        Timeout.start(act);

    }

    public void resume(Activity act) {
            //Timeout.cancel(act);        
        // Check whether the timeout has expired
        long cur_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(act);
        long timeout_start = preferences.getLong("Timeout_key", -1);
        // The timeout never started
        if (timeout_start == -1) {
            return;
        }   
        //long sTimeout = preferences.getLong("idle_delay", 30000);
        long timeout;
        try {
            //timeout = Long.parseLong(sTimeout);
            timeout=idle_delay;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
        }
        // We are set to never timeout
        if (timeout == -1) {
            return;
        }
        if (idle){
        long diff = cur_time - timeout_start;
        if (diff >= timeout) {  
            //Toast.makeText(act, "We have timed out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            showLockDialog();
        }
        }
    }

}
```

Modify your onPause() and onResume() methods in base activity

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mApp.setCurrentActivity(this);
        mApp.resume(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mApp.pause(this);
    }
```